# Groupby for 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like use groupby function based on 3 columns. First column has surname info for families, second column has name of individuals in that families.Third column has which animal every individual has in those families. I want to get information of person with name and surname who has cat or dog and how many of cat or dog those indivual has.
My data looks like

```
Family  SubFamily  Animal

Smith    Karen     Cat

Smith    Karen     Cow

Smith    Karen     Dog

Jackson  Jason     Dog
```

I tried

```
merged_family.groupby(["Family","Animal","SubFamily"]).size().loc[:,'Cat'].loc[:,'Dog']
```

The result might be

Family  SubFamily  Cat Dog

Smith    Karen     1    1

or something similar

It did not work. Could you help me?

Comment: What exactly does "it did not work" mean? What did you expect to get as result in this example?

Comment: I got huge list of error like pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

Comment: I already corrected for F, I wrote wrong in here sorry for this. WhenI try one loc as cat it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a better task for `pivot_table`

```
df_merged.query("Animal.isin(['Cat', 'Dog'])")
  .pivot_table(columns='Animal', index=['Family', 'SubFamily'], aggfunc='size')
  .fillna(0)
  .reset_index()
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

#   Family  SubFamily   Cat Dog
# 0 Jackson Jason       0.0 1.0
# 1 Smith   Karen       1.0 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I got this error 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Can you post the output of `type(merged_family)`

Comment: It is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Strange, can you please do the following and paste the output in the description? `merged_family.head(10).to_json()`

Comment: dataset is much more complicated, it is about biological function of some enzyme. I summarized them as family, family member etc.

Comment: Check the edit using `pivot_table`, but remember, if you don't post the real data, it is harder to check a solution that will fit your needs.